connect streams api, externally transfer a caller while retaining their caller id for the external transfer
Can this be accomplished with connect-streams-api?
Right now I have an outbound dialing campaign and agents in custom UI using connect-api-streams.
Flow:
1.outbound dial using connect sdk StartOutboundVoiceContact
2. consumer enters queue and gets answered by agent
3. agent performs a warm transfer to an external 3rd party
4.agent introduces consumer to third party and disconnects
5.I do this by placing consumer on hold with connection.hold()
6.Then I add a connection using contact.addConnection()
7. Then I conference all 3 using contact.conferenceConnections()
This all works well, very seamless. But, I need the third party to receive the call as the consumer's phone number for look ups that need to occur on their end. Is this at all possible and if so how to accomplish it? I cannot see anything about caller id in the docs.
